# Appending Username and Date to Save As in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I save the excel file using vba code so that the Username and Date are attached in a macro?

Here is the code that I worked on to try to make it work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=(Environ$("Username")) & "_" & Date & "_BKMtracker.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: What is the result of your code? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: You will need a file extension.  "_BKMtracker.xlsx"

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you running this on a previously unsaved file? In that case, you will need to give it a filepath as well as a name.

Comment: @MatthewD the error is: Run time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

The file extension does not solve the problem, but I will update the question to include it because I think that is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I am updating the question, could you see if the following changes will still work for you? If so, then there is definitely an issue with something else besides the code.

Comment: @MatthewD after running this code and recieving the error, if I try to Save As manually, the file name default that is there when I open the window is "2015_BKMtracker." This is not the case if i do not run the code, in that case the default save as name is different. Still though I do not see the file being saved. I assumed that maybe it is saving into a different folder, but I cant find or see any reason that it might do that. Regardless the code is still broken by an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=(Environ$("Username")) & "_" & Date & "_BKMtracker.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

With credit to @MatthewD

Comment: I am recieving the following error: This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the file name text box or select a different type by changing the save as type.

Comment: Still after solving that problem I am getting "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Comment: Unless you format it, `Date` has `/` in it, which are disallowed characters in file names.

Comment: For example, specify the formatting for `Date` to use periods in place of slashes like `Format(Date,"mm.dd.yyyy")` or anything along those lines

Comment: @CodingNovice have you seen padawan's comment above? My date formate is set to dd-mmm-yy; if yours is dd/mm/yyyy then the slashes will get you in trouble. Create a text string instead of a file name. Make it spit out the text string and see if it's a name you could validly save your file as.

Comment: @padawan0007 I tried your method, and It does not work. I am getting a compile error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid properties assignment." I do think you are on the right path. Is there perhaps another way that I can do the same thing?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon You are correct. Removing or simply adding a string in place of date does solve the errors. It did save successfully. The next question is how can I format the Date command manually to report dats perhaps in the form "mmddyyyy" instead.

Comment: Here's the full line of code that I used to test it:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ$("Username") & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_BKMtracker.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SaveDocument()
    Dim username As String
    Dim nowFormated As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim extention As String

    username = Environ("Username") & "_" 'gets the username
    nowFormated = CStr(Format(now, "yymmdd"))  'or every format you like
    path = "D:\" 'Wherever you want to save the file
    filename = "_BKMtracker" 'or what you want
    extention = ".xlsm" 'for example (with macros, else you have to change the FileFormat too)

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & username & nowFormated & filname & extention, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I am going to look at this in a moment. I am first trying to see if I can get the original format to work in the response by @Billy Norbu.